# How to extract values from raster at points with many different rasters and points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1

I have a folder containing 100 DEM rasters.  I have a point file containing thousands of points.  I need to collect raster values at all of these points.

Only some of the rasters intersect with the points, so I need to somehow pull out rasters that intersect with points and then extract values to the points that intersect with the raster.

Comment: Can you use Spatial Analyst tools?

Comment: I need either an idea to use in model builder or python script.

The tools would work great if there was one raster, but to go through 100s of them would take too long.

Comment: Have you got the tool working on one raster and need advice on writing it into a loop? Do you need the model/script from scratch? Are you hung up on just the "does the raster intersect" part, or where?

Answer (score 2):

[Extract multiple values to points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/na/009z0000002s000000/) from Spatial Analyst can deal with multiple raster data as input. But I dont know if it is working with 100 Datasets.

Comment: It would if you batch it or loop it in a script :)

Answer (score 2):

Your rasters, I guess from your description, are not overlapping. Therfore you should create  a [raster mosaic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_mosaic_dataset/009t00000037000000/) (using a gdalbuildvrt or the ArcGIS mosaicing tools) that would behave like a single image. Thenyou can use your tool (extract value to point or extract multivalue to point) only once.

Comment: 1 up for better understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0):

EMVTP (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-multi-values-to-points.htm ExtractMultiValuesToPoints) can extract several attributes, from several rasters at a time. This is how it works:

```
in_point_feature     = "ResearchPlots"
in_raster_and_fields = [["SoilData", "Texture"],      \
                        ["SoilData", "OrganicMatter"],  \
                        ["DEM", "Value"],               \
                        ["RainRaster", "PredictedRain"] \
                       ]
```

ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(in_point_feature, in_raster_and_fields, "NONE")

Comment: Actually, this is part of my question related to EMVTP, posted last Friday.

Comment: The problem (or unexpected return) is that the tool doesn't give you the actual values, but rather the object ID associated to that cell.